# Separate symbolic vector with variables into base vectors and scalar in matlab/octave

Tags: matlab, octave

Is there a way to separate a symbolic vector with variables in it into its base vectors in matlab/octave?

Something like this:

```
[a + b]    [ 0 ]    [ 1 ]    [ 1 ]
[  b  ] => [ 0 ] + a[ 0 ] + b[ 1 ]
[  1  ]    [ 1 ]    [ 0 ]    [ 0 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Octave answer:

I don't know if there's a specific command for it, but for simple cases like this you can easily set your variables to 0 and 1 accordingly and evaluate the resulting parts separately (subtracting the remainder each time). Example:

```
  pkg load symbolic
  a = sym('a');
  b = sym('b');
  v = [ a + b ; b; 1 ];

% Evaluate when a and b = 0
  a = 0; b = 0; Remainder = eval(v);

% Evaluate when a = 1 and b = 0
  a = 1; b = 0; A_vec = eval(v) - Remainder;

% Evaluate when a = 0 and b = 1
  a = 0; b = 1; B_vec = eval(v) - Remainder;

  Remainder, A_vec, B_vec
```

terminal output:

```
Remainder = 

   0
   0
   1

A_vec =

   1
   0
   0

B_vec =

   1
   1
   0
```

Mind you, if you attempt to put it all together, octave will just simplify things again, so if what you want is specifically such a factorisation for 'printout' purposes, then this will not help you.